Highlight with color selected text in an ms access textbox using vba
In an ms access rich text textbox I can select any part of the text and a dialog box shows up then I can click a color  on the highlight dropdown box and the text is highlighted. I want to be able to do the same with vba but can't seem to get the syntax to do the highlighting. I can use selstart and sellength to select the text but unable to find the syntax for highlighting.
[Forms]![myform]![mytextbox].SelText.Highlight = vbGreen
run-time error 424 object required
Update:
Here is my code:
Private Sub Label4_Click()
Dim selSt, selLen As Integer
Dim selT As String
Dim strm As String

With Me.Text0
.SetFocus
selSt = .selStart
selLen = .SelLength
selT = .SelText
strm = "<font  style='BACKGROUND-COLOR:#32F6F6'>" & selT & "</font>"
Me.Text0 = Replace(.Value, selT, strm)
.selStart = selSt
.SelLength = selLen

End With
End Sub 

So one ex i selected 384 characters and only 130 were highlighted. Another ex i selected 93 chr's with a bulleted line to the end of the sentence and it doesn't do anything but when i select that same line with only 80 of the chr's it worked??

That's not how to approach it. Text in a "rich text" textbox is just reduced html formatted text, so you must identify the selected text in the html string and wrap the text part with the tags for highlight.

If I remember correctly, Access uses pre-HTML5 tags for rich text formatting. The set of supported tags is limited. This works for me:
Private Sub Command54_Click()
Dim strS As String, strM As String
With Me.Text52
.SetFocus
.SelStart = 5
.SelLength = 4
strS = .SelText
strM = "<font color=""red"">" & strS & "</font>"
.Value = Replace(.Value, strS, strM)
End With
End Sub


Thank you for the information, it is very intermittent some times it works and other times it does nothing. Also seems to be limited to 130 characters with spaces, and when i select bulleted text it doesn't work with even less characters.

I really don't think this can be practical. Access is not a word processor and trying to use code to make it act like one is just going to frustrate. The rich text toolbar is probably the best you can expect for dynamic text formatting.
